# How to await an IAsyncEnumerable while discarding the results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, iasyncenumerable

I have a function that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable`. I want to `await` it for completion, but I do not care about any of the results. I only care about the side effects of calling the function.

How do can I easily `await` the `IAsyncEnumerable` for completion without using a for loop or turning it into a container (e.g. `ToListAsync`)?

Comment: You'll need to loop over it. You won't know it's "completed" until the very last call to `MoveNextAsync` returns a `ValueTask` which completes with `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`LastOrDefaultAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/LastOrDefault.cs) operator from the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package, and then convert the resulting `ValueTask<T>` to a `Task` by using the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.astask) extension method. For extra convenience you could combine these two operations to one extension method `ToTask`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a Task object that represents the completion of this IAsyncEnumerable.
/// </summary>
public static Task ToTask<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.LastOrDefaultAsync().AsTask();
}
```

But honestly doing a loop manually is simpler and probably more efficient:

```
public async static Task ToTask<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source)
{
    await foreach (var _ in source.ConfigureAwait(false)) { }
}
```

The `LastOrDefaultAsync` operator will preserve in memory the last emitted element during the enumerable's lifetime, which may prevent the element from being garbage collected in a timely manner. You could prevent this from happening by including in the query the [`IgnoreElements`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/System/Linq/Operators/IgnoreElements.cs) operator from the [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) package, but I think it becomes too much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

---

Loger answer: Asking

> How do can I easily await the IAsyncEnumerable for completion without using a for loop or turning it into a container (e.g. ToListAsync)?

Is like asking

> How can I wait for the completion of a Task without using `await` or something like `.Result` or `.Wait()`?

The way to know when an `IAsyncEnumerable` is done is calling `await MoveNextAsync()` on it's iterator and it returning `false`. The concisest way to do that is

```cs
await foreach (var _ in AsyncGenerator()) ; // The semicolon is necessary
```